Trying to apply 2 filters to a score card in looker studio
I am trying to have a score card with two events filtering it. the first is an event that they viewed the page and the second is that they clicked contact us. however when i apply both it says no data
I have tried adding them separately and adding them with the and function. it still is not working i am not sure what to do next

you will need to share more information about your data source and table structure and the query you are using on your filter. It could be that you are using and AND instead of OR on your filter

i am very new so sorry if i don't know much. both filters are when an event name is triggered and right now im using AND
